# Anchor build fails due to a current Rust version (1.59 or above is needed, 1.67 is installed)

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and I am trying to test some sample codebases. When I use

```
anchor build
```

I get the error below. I checked rustc and the 1.67 version is installed and I checked yarn which appears valid. Solana 1.9.5 installed.

> error: package `anchor-attribute-state v0.26.0` cannot be built
> because it requires rustc 1.59 or newer, while the currently active
> rustc version is 1.56.0-dev
> ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-126:~/solana/mycalculatordapp$ rustc --version rustc
> 1.67.0 (fc594f156 2023-01-24)

Answer (score 1):

The Solana CLI tools come bundled with a `rustc` compiler that can be used for on-chain programs. Since you're on 1.9.5, you have a much older version of the bundled Rust compiler.

Please upgrade to something newer, at least the version targeted by Anchor 0.26.0, which is 1.13.5, by running:

```
$ solana-install init 1.13.5
```