# update rustc that anchor uses

Tags: anchor, anchor-lang, rustc

After running `cargo build-bpf` I get the following error:

```
cargo-build-bpf child: rustup toolchain list -v
cargo-build-bpf child: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: package 'anchor-lang v0.27.0' cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.60 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.59.0-dev
```

Sanity checking my rust version with `rustup -V` I get:

`rustup 1.25.2 (2023-02-01)`

`info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.`
`info: The currently active 'rustc' version is 'rustc 1.68.0 (2c8cc3432 2023-03-06)'`

How can I update the rustc that Anchor sees?

Comment: I wondered about something similar a time ago where I overrode toolchain for particular directory and forgot about it. Do you run the `rustup -V` from the same directory where is your anchor project? If you are within the project try to run `rustup show`, that is similar to `-V` just list all toolchain and informs if `directory override` or if `toolchain.toml` is not defined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchor build fails due to a current Rust version (1.59 or above is needed, 1.67 is installed)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5566/anchor-build-fails-due-to-a-current-rust-version-1-59-or-above-is-needed-1-67)

Answer (score 1):

```
rustup install nightly
rustup default nightly
```

Try these? This should update the rust compiler to the latest nightly version and use them too.
You can go back to using the stable versions by replacing `nightly` with `stable`